# How to reload Controller without redirecting/refreshing in cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I would like have to implement Ajax/J-Query for updating database, now after that i need to reload all content of my ctp page in cakephp without refreshing/redirecting.

Is it possible ?

Please help me out.

I tried

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/projectname/Experiences/experienceadd',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'companyname':companyname,'title':title,'monthstart':monthstart,'location':location,'yearstart':yearstart,'yearnextstart':yearnextstart,'monthnextstart':monthnextstart,'presentyeardata':presentyeardata,'description':description},
            success: function (data) {
              if(data)
              {
                mystr = '<div style="display: block; opacity: 1;" class="item mix book mix_all" data-year="2010"> <div class="pubmain"> <div class="pubassets"> <a href="#" class="pubcollapse"> <i class="icon-expand-alt"></i> </a> </div> <h4 class="pubtitle"> ' + companyname + '</h4> <div class="pubauthor"><strong>'+ title +'</strong>,'+ location+'</div> <div class="pubcite">'+ yearstart +' - '+ yearnextstart +' , <strong>'+ presentyeardata + '</strong> </div> </div> <div style="display: none;" class="pubdetails"> <h4>'+ description+'</h4> <div class="pubdetails"> <a class="icon_a icon_right_head" class="exp_rid" id="'+ data +'" href="javascript: void(0);"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Remove</a> <a class="icon_a icon_right_head" class="exp_eid" id="'+ data +'" href="javascript: void(0);"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a> </div> </div></div>';
                $('#pexperience_details').append(mystr);    
                $("#experience-box").hide( 500, function() { });    
                $('#add-experience').show();
                $().toastmessage('showSuccessToast','your skill is successfully Saved');    
              }
              else
              {
                    $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', 'your skill is not successfully Saved');     
              }
            }
        });
```

but this one only add one content area. If my issue is solve than no need of above code.
any idea.....?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. But show us what you have tried

Comment: I tried above things.

Answer (score 1):

Create a whole new Controller action.
For example

```
http://localhost/projectname/Experiences/refresh
```

Here you return all the content you want to be refreshed.
You can call this ajax function WITHIN your current ajax function (if success/data)

Additionally you might want to deactivate the layout

```
$this->layout = false;
```

Comment: You partially correct but it's not accomplish my target. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?
If you want to refresh all, why not call the current page in ajax again and put it into <html>?

Comment: I want to refresh all updated data from database to my current controller ctp but i stay on same place where i am here right now. there is a reason behind that, as in my ctp there is so many jquery and ajax call.

Comment: In your first post you said you need to reload all data.
Now you say you just need to reload the updated data.
Are you just updating a single item and you already got all your information in the 'data' variable?

Comment: right i am telling here again but without my state loss. Is it possible..?